# What is the maximum value / precision that can be stored a sorted set in redis

Tags: redis

What is the maximum value / precision that can be stored as a value that a member can have in a REDIS sorted set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the docs:

> The score values should be the string representation of a **double
>   precision floating point number**.

Source: http://redis.io/commands/ZADD

So, you should have [accuracy to 15 to 17 decimal places](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), and a [max value of about 2^53.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitmax.html)